# How to make ajax request only if username is free,

Tags: validation, jquery

I have already done all validation and showed an error or ok message. Now the final thing comes, I want to check the username availability from a database, so I need to query my server.

```
var b = $("#input_username_holder").val();
if (b != "Username" && b != "" && b.length > 6 && b.length < 17) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "check_username.php",
        data: "b=" + b,
    }).done(function(msg) {
        $("#username_result").html(msg);
    });
}
```

Now, this code works well to show any error that occurs. I want to make an ajax request, but the request should only be made if the username is available:

```
if (fullname valid) {
    if (username is available) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "register.php",
            data: "a=" + a + "&b=" + b + "&c=" + c + "&d=" + d,
        }).done(function(msg) {
            $("#register_box").html(msg);
        });
    }
}
```

---

I am always aware of the threat, that validation with js can be malformed and possibly perform SQL injection on your whole database, so I always do my best to protect my site from any hacking attempt. I do something like this

```
$user_email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'usr_email', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

and furthermore ... I pass the value through this function..

```
function filter($data) {
    $data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));

    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        $data = stripslashes($data);

    $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);

    return $data;
}
```

Is this sufficient enough or you can suggest me something best for the safety...

Comment: You **never** validate with just JavaScript. Ever. I don't need to visit your page at all to send your PHP file a `POST` request, which can be malformed and possibly perform SQL injection on your whole database.

Comment: i am alwez aware of that threat so i alwez do my best to protect my site from any hacking attempt. I do something like this

$user_email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'usr_email', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

and furthermore ... I pass the value through this function..

function filter($data) {
 $data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));
 
 if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
  $data = stripslashes($data);
 
 $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
 
 return $data;
}

Answer (score 1):

I suggest doing something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "register.php",
  data: {'a': a,
         'b': b,
         'c': c,
         'd': d}
}).done(function(msg) {
  if (msg == 'invalid') {
    $("#register_box").html('Username is invalid');
  } else if (msg == 'taken') {
    $("#register_box").html('Username has been taken');
  } else {
    $("#register_box").html('Success');
  }
});
```

Have `register.php` handle all of your username checking and such. If there is an error, just return the error message instead of the success message.

But you absolutely **need** to do serverside validation. You'll pay the price if you don't.